# Centos Postfix mail not received in gmail

Tags: email, postfix-mta

Simple usecase but doesn't work.

I have a web application and want to configure a SMTP server to send emails from application.

Installed mailx as per link - http://tecadmin.net/bash-mail-command-not-found/
All good.

```
Test Sending email as:  echo "This is a test email body  " | mail -s "This is a test email " dk@xxx.com
```

Now I get the following in logs :

```
root@/var/log $ tail -f /var/log/maillog
Jul 19 16:47:57 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/postfix-script[23104]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jul 19 16:47:57 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/master[1466]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 19 16:47:57 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/postfix-script[23184]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jul 19 16:47:57 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/master[23186]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/pickup[23187]: 4163841204: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/cleanup[23194]: 4163841204: message-id=<20160719154812.4163841204@bridgeapps-dev01.localdomain>
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/qmgr[23188]: 4163841204: from=<root@bridgeapps-dev01.localdomain>, size=582, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/smtp[23196]: connect to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[2a00:1450:400c:c09::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/smtp[23196]: 4163841204: to=<dk@xxx.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=0.47, delays=0.02/0.01/0.24/0.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1468943292 l4si11397516wmf.56 - gsmtp)
Jul 19 16:48:12 bridgeapps-dev01 postfix/qmgr[23188]: 4163841204: removed
```

All green, no errors, just as things seem to be too good to be true, I never receive this email in gmail.

What am I missing ?

Thank you,

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First off, you can't send an email from localhost. You need a mail relay. Since you're already using gmail I would recommend this:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/